# symfony twig array key display

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I am trying to get the data from the db using array index however i do not want to iterate.

content table:

```
|id|      content          |active
|1|this is first content   |yes
|2| This is secound Content| yes
```

Controller.php:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entities= $em->getRepository('TestCMSBundle:Content\Content')->GetContents();

return $this->render('TestCMSBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));
```

mytwig:

```
{{ entities.content[0] }}
```

some other contents.... blah blah

```
{{ entities.content[1]}}
```

but i canot seems to get the content.

**Error:
Key "content" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in TestCMSBundle:index.html.twig at line 80**

please i do not want to iterate over the loop like:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
{{ entity.content}}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: `entities.content.0`

Comment: {{ entities.content.0 |raw }}  i still get the same error

Comment: try `{% set entity = entities|first %}`, then you can simply write `entity.content`

Comment: okay i got the first item... but  how can i get second or third index ..???

Comment: Sorry, in your case should be: `entities.0.content`.

Comment: hey just another question when should i use "entities.content.0" ...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use dots instead of brackets:

```
entities.0.content
```

Comment: i tried with {{ entities.0.content }} {{ entities.1.content }} and it worked.... Thanks